# Why does a lone drop fall from my strainer even after tapping it many times?

Tags: everyday-life, home-experiment

I serve fresh made coffee in my cup, collecting the grounds in a strainer. Then I move them back to the pot, add milk to "rinse," and strain again.

My strainer collects about three spoonfuls of coffee grounds, and I tap it against the cup's lip to try and make sure all the liquid comes down before discarding.

Still, even after tapping many times (up to 25 in one trial), a lone drop will always fall when I lift the strainer.

*How come?*

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? First, you add water with coffee in your cup. You use a strainer to push the coffee down. Then what? You add the whole content of the cup back in the pot, rinse off the ground, and use the strainer again? Anyhow, is what you are asking basically why after tapping the strainer with coffee (if this is what you mean with the ground) on it, against the cup's lip many times (up to 25) there will still fall off a drop of water from the strainer?

Answer (score 0):

It's mu guess that the coffee on the rinser is responsible for this. The coffee will get closer to the edge of the strainer and a part of the coffee will fall off.
If you did the same without coffee on the strainer, you can be sure that no extra drop of water falls off after having it tapped 25 times.
The remaining coffee will hold some of the water between its structure, and when you've tapped 25 times this water will be released. The last drop.
Try doing it with a wet but coffee free strainer and see what happens.